# pyodbc - load table using client file - file permission error (sybase). Не получается залить файл в БД при помощи python 3.6

Tags: python, sql, sybase

Пробую сделать быструю загрузку файла в таблицу через python на SAP IQ.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Изначально пользователь имеет доступ на загрузку файлов при помощи инструкции load table(...) using client file ... . Если использовать ПО от сап(interactive sql) все отлично работает , но используя библиотеку sqlanydb получаю ошибку `... (b'Operation failed on file due to file permissions. File: file.txt \n-- (oslib/hos_clientfileio.cxx 143) ', -1006148)`. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что именно  я делаю не так? 
Возможно  стоит добавить какой либо параметр в sqlanydb.connect() 
нормальной документации самостоятельно найти не смог. 
Использовать импорт или инсерты не могу, т.к. файлы в дальнейшем могут приходить большие (от 100К строк и больше) , а load table(...) using client file очень быстро справляется с задачей и практически не нагружает сервер

```
import sqlanydb

conne = sqlanydb.connect(uid='user',
                         pwd='password',
                         databasename = 'dbname',
                         host = 'host.name')

_SQL = '''create table #REP001 (
                       col1 int,
                       col2 int
                     )
;
commit;

load table #REP001
(
  col1 ';',
  col2 '\x0d\x0a'
)
using client file 'file.txt'
            quotes off
            escapes off
;
commit;'''

cur = conne.cursor()
cur.execute(_SQL)

cur.close()
conne.close()
```

Заранее благодарен за ответ, приму любую, даже самую безумную идею

Answer (score 1):

возможно причина в самой библиотеке. попробуйте [эти](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Sybase). не могу сказать обьективно в чём проблема у Вас, так как вопрос не задан полностью со всеми возможными деталями. могу Вам предложить такой вариант: вычитывать файл постепенно и порциями загружать на сервер.